# xampp could not be started in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp

I installed XAMPP for Linux a couple of days ago and was working fine. Today I do wrongly

```
 chmod 777 /opt/lampp
```

then MySQL won't be started. then I completely uninstall XAMPP then again install XAMPP then following message come ::

```
 Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
 XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
 XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
 XAMPP: Another FTP daemon is already running.
 XAMPP for Linux started.
```

then I tried to stop MySQL by typing::

```
 sudo service mysql stop
```

Then It shows that ::
     mysql: unrecognized service

then I tried to stop apache server by typing::

```
 sudo service apach2 stop
```

Then It shows that ::

```
  apache2: unrecognized service
```

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo /etc/init.d mysql restart`